# Kivy Documentation Example error

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to learn how to use RecycleView in kivy because apparently, Listview is outdated now. I tried running this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView


Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

but I keep getting the error:
    kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class

There are no references to ScreenManagement anywhere in the code. I tried importing ScreenManager to my .py file but it didn't work. I don't understand how kivy themselves could put a code that won't work in their own documentation.

Comment: Can we see the link to the specific part of the documentation?

Comment: I have tested in kivy 1.10 with python 2.7.14 and python 3.6.4 and it works correctly, what versions are you using?

Comment: As eyllanesc says, your code works perfectly in kivy 1.10 (`RecicleView` was added in this version). If you used an earlier version you should get an error when importing (`ImportError: There is no module called recycleview`). Something is wrong in your case, regardless of the code, because the error is not reproducible. **Be careful not to have a file called `test.kv` or similar** in your directory that can be automatically loaded (your `App` subclass is called `TestApp`)...